# SQL Pivot IF EXISTS

Tags: sql-server

I think I need a PIVOT but I'm yet to find an example that uses only 1 column.
Current data

```
CustID       Value                
1              A                   
1              B
1              C                  
2              A                   
3              B                  
4              A
4              C
```

I need

```
StudentNumber      A      B     C
1                  Yes   Yes  Yes
2                  Yes   No    No
3                  No    Yes   No
4                  Yes   No    Yes
```

I appreciate it's probably a very simple query but I really am struggling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case statement in the column list checking for null to get the value you need.

```
select P.CustID,
       case when P.A is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as A,
       case when P.B is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as B,
       case when P.C is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as C
from YourTable as T
pivot (min(T.Value) for T.Value in (A,B,C)) as P
```

Or you can use a derived table and isnull in the column list for `No` values.

```
select P.CustID,
       isnull(P.A, 'No') as A,
       isnull(P.B, 'No') as B,
       isnull(P.C, 'No') as C
from (
     select CustID,
            Value,
            'Yes' as S
     from YourTable
     ) as T
pivot (min(T.S) for T.Value in (A,B,C)) as P
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT custid,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN value = 'a' THEN 'YES' else 'NO'
           END) A,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN value = 'b' THEN 'YES' else 'NO'
           END) B,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN value = 'c' THEN 'YES' Else 'NO'
           END) C
FROM   <tablename>
GROUP  BY CustID
```

Comment: can you try it in pivot format..using max case we can do it either way.

Comment: It was that simple!
Thanks very much Pradeep